# $\sum_{k=n}^{2n} \binom{k}{n} 2^{-k}$

Tags: combinatorics

I don't have any idea to solve this problem. Find the value of

$$\sum_{k=n}^{2n} \binom{k}{n} 2^{-k}$$

For every integers $n\geq1$

Could you give me a hint to solve it? Once I get a hint, I will try to solve it again. Thanks

Comment: You haven't tried anything, you haven't even calculated a few values (for $n=1,2,3,$ say) to get a notion what you're dealing with.

Comment: I second what Professor Vector said. Once you have an idea of what this sum yields and you try to prove it via induction, it might be helpful to see that $\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\begin{pmatrix}k\\n\end{pmatrix}2^{-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\begin{pmatrix}k+n\\n\end{pmatrix}2^{-k-n}=2^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\begin{pmatrix}k+n\\k\end{pmatrix}2^{-k}$ (simple index shift)

Comment: Ok. The value is 1, and to prove that the value is 1, I should use induction.

Comment: It's basically this after some simple substitutions [Proof of the identity $2^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n 2^{-k} \binom{n+k}{k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389099/proof-of-the-identity-2n-sum-limits-k-0n-2-k-binomnkk)

Comment: You can also look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2642884/determine-the-value-of-summation-form/2642927?noredirect=1#comment5459285_2642927).